# Retrieve JSON Parameter with AJAX

Tags: json, ajax, undefined

HTML code:

```
<form method="post" action="process.php">
    <button id="process" type="submit">Button</button>
</form>
```

JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function(){
         $('#process').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();  
            $form = $(this).closest('form');

            $.ajax({
              url: $form.attr('action'),
              type: $form.attr('method'),
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(responseJson) {
                 $form.before("<p>"+responseJson.parameter3+"</p>");
              },
              error: function() {
                 $form.before("<p>There was an error processing your request.</p>");
              }
            });
         });         
     });
</script>
```

My process.php page prints the following code:

```
{
  "status" : "success",
  "data" : {
    "parameter1" : "hello",
    "parameter2" : 42,
    "parameter3" : "hello world",
    "parameter4" : "hello again"
  }
}
```

The problem is that I get "undefined" while calling AJAX. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this;

```
$form.before("<p>"+responseJson.data.parameter3+"</p>");
```

you forget `data` to access your `parameter3` value

Comment: that's because of the multidimensional array, right? it works. Thank you

Comment: that not array, that JSON object. array should be like `responseJson["data"]["parameter"]`